# How to return the special character found in string using PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to get the special chars found in string using PHP code, Here is my trial code:

```
 $page_num =">256";
 if(preg_match('^[-<>]+$', $page_num))   
 {
        //Here it should returns special chars present in string..
 }
```

Comment: Is the "special character" always found in the first position? Are the other characters always numeric?

Comment: No it may be anywhere in string like 1-300, <200

Comment: you have missed an ending delimiter. Check my answer below for correction and for other methods as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this

```
$page_num =">256";
 if(preg_match_all('/\W/', $page_num,$matches))
 {
       print_r($matches);
 }
```

Comment: its printing Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => >
        )

)

Comment: that `[0] => > ` is not empty, it found the `>`

Comment: @user3829086 If it worked for you, feel free to mark this answer as correct, so others can see that this is the solution for the problem

Answer (score 1):

What you have missed is **`ending delimiter`**

```
$page_num =">256";
 if(preg_match('^[-<>]+$^', $page_num))   
                        ^// this one
 {
    //Here it should returns special chars present in string..
 }
```

Demo of your code, [**`here`**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4ddae2ea4dc7f4911361a3ba7be229258b0b169)

or you can try this,

```
$string = 'your string here';

if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string))
{
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

One more solution is

```
preg_match('![^a-z0-9]!i', $string);
```